# Foreman 1.7 install error on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, theforeman

I am trying to get a Foreman master setup on a new installation of Ubuntu 14.04.  I am hitting and installation issue that isn't yielding any googable results (or I don't know the right words).

Before running the foreman installer, I ensured that 'ping $(hostname -f)' resulted in my IP address, not 127.0.1.1.

After the installer finished, I was left with this error (machine name redacted):

```
Could not set 'present' on ensure: 422 Unprocessable Entity at 12:/usr/share/foreman-installer/modules/foreman_proxy/manifests/register.pp
Could not set 'present' on ensure: 422 Unprocessable Entity at 12:/usr/share/foreman-installer/modules/foreman_proxy/manifests/register.pp
/Stage[main]/Foreman_proxy::Register/Foreman_smartproxy[abc.xyz.com]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Could not set 'present' on ensure: 422 Unprocessable Entity at 12:/usr/share/foreman-installer/modules/foreman_proxy/manifests/register.pp
/Stage[main]/Foreman_proxy::Register/Foreman_smartproxy[abc.xyz.com]: Failed to call refresh: missing param 'id' in parameters
/Stage[main]/Foreman_proxy::Register/Foreman_smartproxy[abc.xyz.com]: missing param 'id' in parameters
```

From the /var/log/foreman-installer/foreman-installer.log (machine name redacted):

```
[DEBUG 2014-12-09 16:01:31 main]  Puppet::Type::Foreman_smartproxy::ProviderRest: feature foreman_api is missing
[ INFO 2014-12-09 16:01:59 main] E, [2014-12-09T16:01:59.627479 #3981] ERROR -- : 422 Unprocessable Entity
[ INFO 2014-12-09 16:01:59 main] {
[ INFO 2014-12-09 16:01:59 main]     "error"[0;37m => [0m{
[ INFO 2014-12-09 16:01:59 main]                    "id"[0;37m => [0m[1;31mnil[0m,
[ INFO 2014-12-09 16:01:59 main]                "errors"[0;37m => [0m{
[ INFO 2014-12-09 16:01:59 main]             "base"[0;37m => [0m[
[ INFO 2014-12-09 16:01:59 main]                 [1;37m[0] [0m[0;33m"Unable to communicate with the proxy: ERF12-2530 [ProxyAPI::ProxyException]: Unable to detect features ([RestClient::RequestTimeout]: Request Timeout) for proxy https://abc.xyz.com:8443/features"[0m,
[ INFO 2014-12-09 16:01:59 main]                 [1;37m[1] [0m[0;33m"Please check the proxy is configured and running on the host."[0m
[ INFO 2014-12-09 16:01:59 main]             ]
[ INFO 2014-12-09 16:01:59 main]         },
[ INFO 2014-12-09 16:01:59 main]         "full_messages"[0;37m => [0m[
[ INFO 2014-12-09 16:01:59 main]             [1;37m[0] [0m[0;33m"Unable to communicate with the proxy: ERF12-2530 [ProxyAPI::ProxyException]: Unable to detect features ([RestClient::RequestTimeout]: Request Timeout) for proxy https://abc.xyz.com:8443/features"[0m,
[ INFO 2014-12-09 16:01:59 main]             [1;37m[1] [0m[0;33m"Please check the proxy is configured and running on the host."[0m
[ INFO 2014-12-09 16:01:59 main]         ]
[ INFO 2014-12-09 16:01:59 main]     }
[ INFO 2014-12-09 16:01:59 main] }
[ERROR 2014-12-09 16:01:59 main]  Could not set 'present' on ensure: 422 Unprocessable Entity at 12:/usr/share/foreman-installer/modules/foreman_proxy/manifests/register.pp
```

Given the nature of the error, I attempted to re-create the smart proxy using the Web UI.  There, I encountered this error (machine name redacted):

```
Unable to communicate with the proxy: ERF12-2530 [ProxyAPI::ProxyException]: Unable to detect features ([RestClient::RequestTimeout]: Request Timeout) for proxy https://abc.xyz.com:8443/features
Please check the proxy is configured and running on the host.
```

Finally, I double checked that the proxy is running:

```
service foreman-proxy status
 * foreman-proxy is running
```

The firewall is turned off and apt-get upgrade has been ran.  Other than that, it should be a pretty standard installation of Ubuntu 14.04.

Has anyone encountered this error?  Any other troubleshooting tips to try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same setup and same result. Just did a fresh install of Foreman 1.6 without this problem. The Foreman_smartproxy register.pp has not changed between 1.6 and 1.7, but apparently something has.

Thanks to Dominic on irc channel #theforman,
the solution seems to be a change in the settings:

Adminster > Settings > General and check proxy_request_timeout is set to 60

Re-run installer

PS I Also changed the idle_timeout to 60

Comment: Specifically when you see "[RestClient::RequestTimeout]: Request Timeout" in the log.  I think this *might* be fixed in 1.7.1.

Comment: Thanks! I will have to check out that irc channel.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm. Foreman 1.7 comes with weird setting by default. I changed Adminster > Settings > General and check proxy_request_timeout is set to 60 and I was able to add a new proxy even without re-run the installer.

Thanks a lot!